# How to improve the search speed when using left join SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

In SQL Server, I query data from two `VIEW` to get records whose `OLDPID` are -1,-2:

```
SELECT 
    T1.*, T2.LEAF 
FROM 
    (SELECT * 
     FROM VIEW_OBJECT_TREE_DATA  
     WHERE OLDPID IN (-1, -2)) T1
LEFT JOIN 
    VIEW_OBJECT_TREE_DATA_GROUP T2 ON T1.NODEID = T2.NODEPID 
WHERE 
    T1.STATE = 1
```

But it takes 3-4 seconds to get the result.

How can I modify this SQL query to improve its speed?

`VIEW_OBJECT_TREE_DATA` has OLDPID, OLDID and NAME columns with 450000 records.`VIEW_OBJECT_TREE_DATA_GROUP` has NODEPID and LEAF with 65000 records.

Below is some sql of view and function:
VIEW_OBJECT_TREE_DATA:

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.VIEW_OBJECT_TREE_DATA
AS
SELECT(SELECT[dbo].[FNNC_GET_TREE_GUID](0, OBJECT_ID)) AS NODEID,
                    (SELECT[dbo].[FNNC_GET_TREE_GUID](0, PARENT_ID)) AS NODEPID, 'MY_OBJECT_TABLE' AS[TABLE],   
                OBJECT_ID AS OLDID, PARENT_ID AS OLDPID, OBJECT_NAME COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT AS NAME,   
                OBJECT_CODE COLLATE database_default AS CODE, OBJECT_TYPE COLLATE database_default AS TYPE,  
                OBJECT_STATE as STATE
FROM dbo.MY_OBJECT_TABLE
WHERE   OBJECT_STATE <> -1
UNION
SELECT(SELECT[dbo].[FNNC_GET_TREE_GUID](1, INDICATOR_ID)) AS NODEID,
                    (SELECT[dbo].[FNNC_GET_TREE_GUID](0, OBJECT_ID)) AS NODEPID, 'MY_INDICATOR_TABLE' AS[TABLE],   
                INDICATOR_ID AS OLDID, OBJECT_ID AS OLDPID, INDICATOR_NAME COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT AS NAME,   
                INDICATOR_CODE COLLATE database_default AS CODE, INDICATOR_TYPE COLLATE database_default AS TYPE,  
                INDICATOR_STATE AS STATE
FROM      dbo.MY_INDICATOR_TABLE
WHERE   INDICATOR_STATE <> -1
```

VIEW_OBJECT_TREE_DATA_GROUP :

```
CREATE VIEW VIEW_OBJECT_TREE_DATA_GROUP  
AS
SELECT NODEPID,COUNT(0) AS LEAF FROM VIEW_OBJECT_TREE_DATA GROUP BY NODEPID
```

Function:

```
USE[MY_DATABASE]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER FUNCTION[dbo].[FNNC_GET_TREE_GUID](@TYPE INT, @ID INT)
RETURNS UNIQUEIDENTIFIER
AS
BEGIN

    RETURN CAST(CAST(@TYPE AS binary(4))+CAST(@ID AS varbinary(28)) AS UNIQUEIDENTIFIER)
END
```

Comment: Do you have any indexes? Any foreign key constraints that help the RDBMS? Also, you have an odd way of writing that query, I must say.  Why the subquery instead of just the table in the `FROM` and having 2 clauses in the final `WHERE`? Also, I really suggest better aliasing. [Bad Habits to Kick : Using table aliases like (a, b, c) or (t1, t2, t3)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3). `OTD` and `OTDG` would seem appropriate aliases here.

Comment: I would expect someone with more than 10k reputation to provide enough information to answer the question. What does the execution plan say, for example?

Comment: @Larnu OK,I will use aliases.This is SQL VIEW not basic table.And I just want to join them.

Comment: That doesn't change the rest of my comment, @Ryan .

Comment: @HoneyBadger Sorry, I am not so familiar with sql.I am querying other's existing SQL VIEW.

Comment: Please add the execution plan (preferably on pastetheplan.com), and the view definitions.

Comment: Creating an index which combines the 2 fields of the T1 view (VIEW_OBJECT_TREE_DATA) OLDPID, NODEID could tune the performance,
Can you please share the sql content of this view ?

Comment: @planben I update the sql now

Comment: @HoneyBadger I update the view definitions

Comment: The execution plan would also be very useful to identify the bottleneck. Although it seems very likely to be the GROUP BY NODEPID, which can't be helped adding any INDEX because NODEPID is not a column but the result of a function.

Comment: Ok so the NODEID field is not indexable because it is a field which is based on a function, is it possible to add it as a unique identifier to dbo.MY_OBJECT_TABLE table without using the function? that way you'll be able to index the field and it will improve the performance.

Comment: @planben I think you are right, if he adds an indexed unique identifier to MY_OBJECT_TABLE and MY_INDICATOR_TABLE instead of that function calculated NODEPID then the SQL engine should be able to optimize the query.

Comment: @MarcGuillot - yep, though I am not sure he would like to change the table structure and that is my concern.

Comment: @planben.No,I can not change this table structure

Answer (score 1):

You can directly join those two views without having to use a subquery.

```
select TD.*, DG.LEAF 
from VIEW_OBJECT_TREE_DATA as TD
     left join VIEW_OBJECT_TREE_DATA_GROUP as DG on DG.NODEPID = TD.NODEID
where TD.OLDPID in (-1, -2) and
      TD.STATE = 1
```

Although without seeing those views and the execution plan there is no way of knowing what slows you down.

Comment: OK,I will not use subquery now, thanks.I also show my view sql in my post now.